# JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(); in System.Text.Json not deserialize correctly

Tags: c#, json, json.net, system.text.json

I'm trying to deserialize [this](http://services.buildandshoot.com/serverlist.json) json with `System.Text.Json`, but I can't, and I don't know why it's not working, here's the result:

**PS:** And I don't know if that influences, but the array where the elements are inside, has no name, just enter the link and see
**PS/2:** This happens on any object in the list

[image]

Here is my code:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace AceOfSpadesServersList
{
    internal sealed class ServerList
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; internal set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("identifier")]
        public string IP { get; internal set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("map")]
        public string Map { get; internal set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("game_mode")]
        public string GameMode { get; internal set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("country")]
        public string Country { get; internal set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("latency")]
        public ushort Latency { get; internal set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("players_current")]
        public byte CurrentPlayers { get; internal set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("players_max")]
        public byte MaxPlayers { get; internal set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("last_updated")]
        public uint LastUpdated { get; internal set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("game_version")]
        public string GameVersion { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AceOfSpadesServersList;

namespace AceOfSpadesServersList
{
    public class AceOfSpadesServersList
    {
        private const string BuildAndShootServersList = "http://services.buildandshoot.com/serverlist.json";

        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public AceOfSpadesServersList()
        {
            if (_httpClient is null)
                this._httpClient = new HttpClient();
        }

        public async Task GetAllServersAsync()
        {
            var json = string.Empty;

            var streamHttpResponse = await this._httpClient.GetStreamAsync(BuildAndShootServersList);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(streamHttpResponse, Encoding.UTF8))
                json = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

            var serverList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ServerList[]>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong, but I tested the exact same code using `Newtonsoft.Json`, and I just changed the `JsonPropertyName` attribute to `JsonProperty` and `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ServerList[]>(json);` to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerList[]>(json);` and works normally, it just doesn't work in the standard C# library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.Text.Json` respects the visibility constraints you impose on the class. Remove the `internal` on your setters.

Comment: Or mark them with [JsonInclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonincludeattribute?view=net-5.0)

Comment: With C# 9, it might even work with `init`.

Answer (score 4):

i have the same problem and fix it by add PropertyNamingPolicy

```
   var serverList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ServerList[]>(json, new 
    JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    });
```